# How to create a table that indicates existence of factor levels in several data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have several data.frames that have some common factor variables. However, missing observations cause discrepancies and some levels go missing in some of the data.frames. I would like to create a summary table that indicates which data.frames include the levels and which do not.

Like this

FACTOR1

```
            DF.1   DF.2
  LEVEL1    TRUE   TRUE
  LEVEL2    TRUE   FALSE
```

where LEVEL1 of FACTOR1 appears in both data.frames DF.1 and DF.2 whereas LEVEL2 appears only in DF.1 but not in DF.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.1 = data.frame(var=c('a','b','c','d'))
df.2 = data.frame(var=c('a','b','c'))
df.3 = data.frame(var=c('a','d','d'))

ldf = list()
for(i in 1:3){
    ldf[[length(ldf)+1]] =get(paste0('df','.',i))
}
ll = sapply(ldf, function(x) {c(levels(x$var))})
levellist = unique(unlist(ll))

levellist
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

sapply(ldf, function(x) {levellist %in% levels(x$var) })
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```